# Does the two slit experiment fall apart if there is dust in the room?

Tags: waves, interference, double-slit-experiment

All the pictures and videos of the two slit experiment show the photons hitting the back screen in the interference pattern.  Does this fall apart if there is dust in the air and the photons hit a speck of dust?  Does the wave function collapse at the speck of dust?

Comment: Yes, it is the collapse of the wave that will allow the light (photon: information vector) to visualize its existence between the screen and the two slits as in this experiment*, there will only be an attenuation** the intensity of the interference fringes .                          *https://youtu.be/Hr5MxFnioow?t=20         **https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attenuation_coefficient

Comment: @TheTiler  That video says it all. Thanks.